# Memory Complexity For Recursive Functions

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, linked-list, big-o

What is the memory complexity of the following function?

```
def remove_nodes_with_value_recursive(head,x):
  if not head:
    return
  head.next = remove_nodes_with_value_recursive(head.next, x)
  return head.next if head.val is x else head
```

My guess is O(n) because N recursive calls are made, so it adds those parameters N times to the stack. Is that correct? If not, please explain why.

Comment: It depends, best case is O(1) (if the list is empty), average and worst case are O(n).

Comment: @JonnyHenly Well, for specific input sizes, everything is O(1). =)

Comment: @jamesdlin : ) just wanted to cover all the bases.